# How to start creating a BHO in C#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I need to create a BHO in C#.
Any documentation available other than the typical Microsoft C++ example?

How do I start?
Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that difficult really, but you will have to get your hands dirty with COM interop. I just recently did this for a line-of-business application. Basically you gotta implement IObjectWithSite in your add-in and from there you just hook up to the WebBrowser events the same as you would with an embedded WebBrowser control.

Here is an example. http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040331.htm