# Need help getting started with programmatically customizing Windows Explorer

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, windows-explorer

I want to make an addin to Windows Explorer toolbar using .NET 4. Can anyone please provide sample code?

Comment: You mean you want to write a shell extension?

Comment: start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940376(v=vs.85).aspx and work out what type of sample fits you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "My error, I meant toolbar"

Toolbars for both Explorer and Internet Explorer can be developed as [Browser Helper Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object).

It is a pain to do in C# *(involves a lot of COM interop)*, but it can be done.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467805/how-to-start-creating-a-bho-in-c).

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately, none give me good examples on how to do it in Windows Explorer. I need like a hello word example using .NET.

Comment: @Phil: That's exactly what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004) is.

Answer (score 1):

Shell extension sample code is included in [Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/).
You can find the sample at [All-In-One Windows Shell Code Samples](http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WinShell)